# Getting Beautiful Soup to read .htm files

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Help!  I am new to programming, trying to learn in a class.  I'm trying to do a basic webcrawler, but for some reason Beautiful Soup isn't recognizing links for .htm files.  Can you help?

Here's the code:

```
import re, urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print("Enter the URL you wish to crawl (include the 'http://'):")
myurl = input("@> ")


root = re.sub("/\w+\.htm", "", myurl)


html = urllib.request.urlopen(myurl)    
html = html.read()  
html = str(html)
links = re.findall('href=\.+.htm">', html)
```

**Edited to add code from comment**

```
link = str(link) 
link = re.sub(".htm>'", ".htm$", link) 
link = re.sub("'$", "", link) 
if not re.match("^(http|www)", link): 
    link = root + "/" + str(link) 
    current_html = urllib.request.urlopen(link) 
    current_html = current_html.read() 
    current_soup = BeautifulSoup(current_html, "html.parser") 
    current_clean_text = current_soup.getText()
```

Comment: Where do you use BeautifulSoup?  You should have a call like `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`.  Also use different variable names, don't keep reassigning `html`.

Comment: Sorry, like I said I'm pretty new to this.  Here's the rest of the code; part of the problem is that I don't understand how it works but I can't find anything online that explains it in very basic terms.

for link in links:
    link = str(link)
    link = re.sub(".htm>'", ".htm$", link)
    link = re.sub("'$", "", link)
    if not re.match("^(http|www)", link):
        link = root + "/" + str(link)
    current_html = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    current_html = current_html.read()
    current_soup = BeautifulSoup(current_html, "html.parser")
    current_clean_text = current_soup.getText()

Comment: do a `print(current_soup)` and see what you get

Comment: I'm trying to print the links it pulls but there's nothing.  It doesn't recognize anything from the source code even though I can see .htm links.

Comment: You have to give us some sort of output or input to see what you are working with.  What is `current_html`?  What is `current_soup`? Do you even get in the `if` statement?